# Trace HID device traffic on Linux

Tags: c++, usb, hid, lsusb

I'm rewriting software for a HID device reader to allow Linux support and I'm having a bit of trouble debugging it.  On Windows, I use a tool called [Busdog](http://code.google.com/p/busdog/), which lets you pick a device and log the write/read reports.  It manages this by installing a custom driver to sniff the traffic.

The Linux-based library I'm using communicates directly with the device using lsusb, so there is no driver interaction.  Does anyone know how I might trace the traffic between my app and the USB device?

Note: I've tried dumping the data from my app before writing to the device, and everything looks fine.  If I run my compiled app in Windows, however, busdog is showing incorrect data being written to the device. This indicates there's a problem with the library I'm using (hidapi.h).  I'd like to confirm this, if I can, in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) can capture USB traffic as well as network traffic.  It doesn't present the data as nicely as busdog (there's a lot of extra stuff in there, not just the HID data), but it does the job.